Python API for Drag and Drop Events?
I am trying to create an add-on for Blender that uses a drag and drop event, similar to the Drag and Drop from the Outliner, and various other areas of Blender, however, I have no clue where to find such a handler for what I'm trying to do.
For context, I am trying to create a script where upon activation thanks to a persistent handler, it overrides the current Drag and Drop feature of the Outliner, and makes it so that when a Light, or Camera is selected, and dropped into the 3D Viewport from the Outliner, it activates the Set Active Object as Camera operator.
This is something that is native to the 3D Animation software I used to use, and while I know I can just select the light, and press CTRL Numpad 0/0, it just makes more sense to drag and drop it from the Outliner since you have to select the light anyway.
Any and all help would be appreciated. If your solution works, you'll see your name appear in the add-on info page, along with getting a discount for products on my Gumroad store if you're interested.

it's not possible with the python API, it's not exposed yet.

I'm surprised. We're on 4.1, going into 4.2 now.
